# compare two files(by diffrent seperators) by 4 columns and back the desired out put

Tags: awk

I have two files. file 1 has 16 columns with separator "," and file2  with about 40 columns with separator "tab". 
i want to compare two files. if the columns 1,2,3,4 of file 1 are same as columns 1,2,4,5 0f file2, the output file contain all of information of file2 and corresponding column16 of file 1.

file 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1GiH.png)

file2: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z7sm.png)

```
 awk 'BEGIN {OFS="/t"} NR==FNR{FS=",";a[$1,$2,$3,$4];b[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$16}{FS="/t";if (($1,$2,$4,$5) in a) print $0,b[$1,$2,$4,$5]}' <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k2 file2) >output
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$16; next} 
      ($1,$2,$4,$5) in a {print $0,a[$1,$2,$4,$5]}' FS=, file1 FS='\t' file2
```

no need to presort the files.